# .php website crashes on wake-up from hibernate

Tags: php, google-chrome, crash

I have been working on my .php site and I have noticed that upon waking from hibernation, the google chrome "this page has crashed" screen appears until I refresh.

Would anyone happen to know of any obvious reason I may have missed? (tried searching online but no luck except a php forum which has the same issue)

I have a feeling it might be to do with the variables dictating which page to load but I don't know what my next step would be to address this.

```
<?php
$tma="elements/the-mist-arcane-nav.php";
    include "elements/header.php";

    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        switch($_GET['page']){
            case "the-mist-arcane":
                include "$tma";
                include "pages/the-mist-arcane.php";
                break;

                case "story":
                    include "$tma";
                    include "pages/the-mist-arcane/story.php";
                    break;
                case "classes":
                    include "$tma";
                    include "pages/the-mist-arcane/classes.php";
                    break;
            case "home":
                include "pages/home.php";
                break;
        }
    }else{
        include "pages/home.php";
    }

    include "elements/footer.php";

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try to hibernate with google-chrome inspector turned on to see what the browser is trying to do...

Comment: is it running on a local webserver? what webserver? what OS are you using?

Comment: There is a very narrow chance (redirection loop?) that Chrome crash is related your back-end(php) code. It's much more probable that your front-end (css/html/js) is crashing the website (infinite loop in JS?).

Comment: It's hosted on Arvixe with Cpanel. OS is win 8.1. Will try hibernating with inspector open to see what comes up, could be javascript possibly

Comment: okay, the crash only seems to occur after some time it would seem, it only happens when I wake my computer in the morning so i wont be able to inspect until tomorrow morning, anything I could try before then? Thanks for the responses